# How to do a set a threshold operation to the element in a tensor in Tensorflow?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

When I get the output of the network, it is a tensor with the size like [batch_size, height, weight].The content is the probability. What I want to do is to set a threshold to the tensor, and do the binarization processing. So what should I do to the tensor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tf.clip_by_value`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value):

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.random_uniform(shape=(2, 3, 3), minval=-1, maxval=3)
b = tf.clip_by_value(a, 0, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    A, B = sess.run([a, b])
    print A, '\n'
    print B
```

Here everything above 1 will become 1, everything below 0 will be 0. Everything else will stay the same.

Also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43836655/1090562) which does a similar thing but convert everything to 0 or 1:

Comment: However, the contents in my tensor is probability, so it's already in the range [0,1]. What I want to do is to set a threshold like 0.9, everything above 0.9 will become 1, everything below 0.9 will be 0.

Comment: 1) how should I guess this from your question? 2) have you read the question I linked? It solves exactly the problem you described.

Comment: Sorry about my carelessness. One more problem. In the answer you provide to me, I have to use the sess.run(), then I can get the result right? However, in my code, I already define a graph and some placaholders. If I write something like  sess.run(pred), I will get error message:

Comment: InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [50,240,240,3]
  [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[50,240,240,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Comment: You must feed the values of any placeholders you use as the second argument to sess.run().